# Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XXX using oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Tags: oracle, jdbc, io, ojdbc

This is the error message I get when I try to connect my local DataBase to the NetBeans IDE. I hardly have any experience using netbeans either, the URL I used to connect using Oracle thin is:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:KJT
```

The corresponding error is:

> Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:KJT using oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection).

Please help me out.

Comment: OK, can you tnsping the database from your workstation. Is the database server actually running on your workstation?

Answer (score 1):

this error means once check your port number

the oracle default port number is 1521 but i think u r changed at the time of oracle installation time so once check it

as well as oracle service name also u mentioned "KJT" once check!

Comment: KJT is the SID for my database... As for port number I was recently able to connect through it when I was connected to my broadband connection... As soon as I disconnect from the internet I loose the connection to my local database...

Comment: I need to be able to connect to the database on my computer while I am offline which I was able to successfully achieve on my friend's laptop using his database and netbeans on that system...